# No bash completion with gcutil

Tags: google-compute-engine, bash-completion, gcutil

I have just installed Google Cloud SDK, and I accepted the installation of **bash completion**, but I only have completion for `gcloud` and **not `gcutil`**.

Is it possible to have bash completion for `gcutil` too ? How ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command completion only works on **gcloud** not gsutil, gcutil etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, at least, I know that I'm not the only one who has no bash completion for `gcutil`, though it's a pity, since most of the time, I think that we use more `gcutil` than `gcloud`...

Comment: I think that we will soon find all of the gcutil, gsutil tools get merged into the gcloud tool.